# Regular Expression match [word] [space] [number]

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm trying to extract some strings from a list with the following patternt: [word] [space] [integer].

Some examples of words and the match function result would be:

```
"Test 1" = true
"Test 29" = true
"Test 1a" = false
"Test1" = false
"Test 12 abc" = false
"Test a 1" = false
"Something Test 1" = false
```

Comment: Can you ask a more specific question? That's a story, not a question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try this

```
^\w+?\s\d+$
```

This match, from the begining of the string `^`:

- `\w+?` as many letters as need be, until the space
- `\s` a space
- `\d+` as many numbers as need be

Until the end of the string `$`

If `\w` is too inclusive for your need, for it does match [a-zA-Z0-9_], you could go for this instead: `^[a-zA-Z]+?\s\d+$`, where only letters will be matched, not numbers or underscore.

Comment: Ah, I was missing the ^ for the beginning of string. Thanks, ^Test\s\d+$ didi the trick.

Comment: `^\w+?\s\d+$` this expression will fail with `123 1` but the other one works well `^[a-zA-Z]+?\s\d+$`
  https://regexr.com/59950